# What "version" of a php page would crawlers see?

Tags: php

I am considering building a website using php to deliver different html depending on browser and version. A question that came to mind was, which version would crawlers see? What would happen if the content was made different for each version, how would this be indexed?

Comment: what's with all the downvotes? it isn't that bad of a question. +1

Comment: @uku I'm assuming it's the implication that it could be used for something less than honest representation of content. Certainly not my intention but I have my answer, and for this I am grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crawlers would see the page that you have specified for them to see via your user-agent handling.

Your idea seems to suggest trying to trick the indexer somehow, don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

The crawlers see the page you show them.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3728492/502381) for info on how Googlebot identifies itself as. Also remember that if you show different content to the bot than what the users see, your page might be excluded from Google's search results.

As a sidenote, in most cases it's really not necessary to build separate HTML for different browsers, so it might be best to rethink that strategy altogether which will solve the search engine indexing issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the `User-Agent` HTTP Header, which is often sent by the browsers, to identify the browsers/versions that interest you, and send a content that would be different in some cases.

So, the crawlers would receive the content you'd send for their specific `User-Agent` string -- or, if you don't code a specific case for those, your default content.

Still, note that Google doesn't really appreciate if you send it content that is not the same as what real users get *(and if a someone using a given browser sends a link to some friend, who doesn't see the same thing as he's using another browser, this will not feel "right")*.

<sub>Basically : sending content that differs on the browser is not really a good practice ; and should in most/all cases be avoided</sub>

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what content you'll serve to bots. Crawlers usually identify themselves as some bot or other in the user agent header, not as a regular browser. Whatever you serve these clients is what they'll index.

Answer (score 0):

The crawler obviously only sees the version your server hands to it.

Answer (score 0):

- If you create a designated version for the search engine, this version would be indexed (and eventually makes you banned from the index).
- If you have a version for the default/undetected browser - this one.
- If you have no default version - nothing would be indexed.

Sincerely yours, colonel Obvious.

PS. Assuming you are talking of contents, not markup. Search engines do not index markup.

Comment: My idea was simply to include some inline styling for older browsers to achieve similar visual effect. Not something I may actually do, but it piqued my curiosity as did the inherent question. Sorry it was so obvious!